# Using a relative path for File() in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am working in Flutter and trying to open a json file in my assets folder. I found I can use the File() method, but it only seems to take an absolute path. Is there a way I can convert this to a relative path? I've tried using the relative path to the file already, but it returns an error saying no such file.

Here is the code so far. Basically I want to get the json file, and return it as a string (in the function readFileSync() below). Then I use that data to create a List object. If there's a better way to read a file into Flutter, I'm open to that too!

```
List<Answers> myFunction2() {
  String arrayObjsText = readFileSync();
  //print(arrayObjsText);

  var tagObjsJson = jsonDecode(arrayObjsText)['tags'] as List;
  var tagObjs =
      tagObjsJson.map((tagJson) => Answers.fromJson(tagJson)).toList();

  return tagObjs;
}

String readFileSync() {
  String contents = new File(
          '/Users/pstumbaugh/Documents/Computer Science/CS492 Mobile Dev/Dart-Flutter-CallMeMaybe/project3/assets/answers.json')
      .readAsStringSync();
  return contents;
}
```

I don't know much about how Futures work. I tried with those, but it seems like it always returns a Future and I'm not sure how to unpack that down to just a string without having to make everything async functions, which then led to problems when I try to get the List in my widgets on the main page...

Answer (score 1):

You should to get assets not from relative path from your PC. When you install an app for a device or a emulator/simulator, it is can't access files on your computer. In few words, you can do it with `loadString` method from `flutter/services.dart` package (it is in Flutter SDK by default):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

final data = rootBundle.loadString('assets/answers.json');
```

And make sure that you declared assets in `pubspec.yaml` config. [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) is an official tutorial for how to work with assets.